# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000068: Servlet path match failed

Tags: jboss

I am migrating my application from websphere to jboss EAP 7.1.0 but I am getting following error.

**Error**:

> ERROR [default task-37] nmateti ActionExceptionHandler.logException(143) | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000068: Servlet path match failed
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatchesData.getServletHandlerByPath(ServletPathMatchesData.java:83)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatches.getServletHandlerByPath(ServletPathMatches.java:88)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:74)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.getRequestDispatcher(ServletContextImpl.java:330)
>       at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.handleAsForward(PerformForward.java:93)
>       at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.perform(PerformForward.java:82)
>       at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractPerformForward.execute(AbstractPerformForward.java:51)
>       at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:48)
>       at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
>       at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
>       at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
>       at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:280)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1858)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:459)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>       at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:119)
>       at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:55)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at com.wm.snapshot.webapp.filter.StackFilter.doFilter(StackFilter.java:52)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at com.wm.snapshot.webapp.filter.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:93)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:264)
>       at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
>       at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
>       at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
>       at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:110)
>       at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
>       at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
>       at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
>       at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:217)
>       at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
>       at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:193)
>       at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
>       at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:148)
>       at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.ajaxanywhere.AAFilter.doFilter(AAFilter.java:65)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default configurations? Particularly the default servlet? Cause this error is related to if there is no default servlet and a request does not match a mapped servlet, so a exception is thrown.

getServletHandlerByPath - illegalArgumentException UT00068:

```
ERROR [default task-37] nmateti ActionExceptionHandler.logException(143) | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000068: Servlet path match failed at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatchesData.getServletHandlerByPath(ServletPathMatchesData.java:83) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatches.getServletHandlerByPath
```

Also consider also migrating for EAP 7.2 CP 3, which was released last week, or at least to EAP 7.1.6, which corrected several bugs on EAP 7.0.0 and 7.1.0.

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly the web.xml should look for default configuration. Because I tried few things nothing works out.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution: just need to add `redirect = true` in the config file for that particular path/methods where mapping has been done.